# How to fix this error in drupal? Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base.type' in 'field list'

Tags: php, sql, drupal-7

Please someone could help me I am new in drupal and I am making a classified drupal site, everything was ok but I Installed the media module and when I was uninstalling this module my site shows me this error and I dont know how to solve it, I cant see anything in my site now This site is in my local server WAMPSERVER the error is this

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base.type' in 'field list': SELECT base.fid AS fid, base.uid AS uid, base.filename AS filename, base.uri AS uri, base.filemime AS filemime, base.filesize AS filesize, base.status AS status, base.timestamp AS timestamp, base.type AS type FROM {file_managed} base WHERE (base.fid IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0, :db_condition_placeholder_1, :db_condition_placeholder_2, :db_condition_placeholder_3, :db_condition_placeholder_4, :db_condition_placeholder_5, :db_condition_placeholder_6, :db_condition_placeholder_7, :db_condition_placeholder_8, :db_condition_placeholder_9, :db_condition_placeholder_10, :db_condition_placeholder_11, :db_condition_placeholder_12, :db_condition_placeholder_13, :db_condition_placeholder_14, :db_condition_placeholder_15, :db_condition_placeholder_16, :db_condition_placeholder_17, :db_condition_placeholder_18, :db_condition_placeholder_19, :db_condition_placeholder_20, :db_condition_placeholder_21, :db_condition_placeholder_22, :db_condition_placeholder_23, :db_condition_placeholder_24, :db_condition_placeholder_25, :db_condition_placeholder_26, :db_condition_placeholder_27, :db_condition_placeholder_28, :db_condition_placeholder_29, :db_condition_placeholder_30, :db_condition_placeholder_31, :db_condition_placeholder_32, :db_condition_placeholder_33, :db_condition_placeholder_34, :db_condition_placeholder_35, :db_condition_placeholder_36, :db_condition_placeholder_37, :db_condition_placeholder_38, :db_condition_placeholder_39, :db_condition_placeholder_40, :db_condition_placeholder_41, :db_condition_placeholder_42, :db_condition_placeholder_43, :db_condition_placeholder_44, :db_condition_placeholder_45, :db_condition_placeholder_46, :db_condition_placeholder_47, :db_condition_placeholder_48, :db_condition_placeholder_49, :db_condition_placeholder_50, :db_condition_placeholder_51, :db_condition_placeholder_52, :db_condition_placeholder_53, :db_condition_placeholder_54, :db_condition_placeholder_55)) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 2 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 3 [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => 4 [:db_condition_placeholder_4] => 5 [:db_condition_placeholder_5] => 6 [:db_condition_placeholder_6] => 7 [:db_condition_placeholder_7] => 8 [:db_condition_placeholder_8] => 9 [:db_condition_placeholder_9] => 10 [:db_condition_placeholder_10] => 12 [:db_condition_placeholder_11] => 13 [:db_condition_placeholder_12] => 14 [:db_condition_placeholder_13] => 15 [:db_condition_placeholder_14] => 16 [:db_condition_placeholder_15] => 17 [:db_condition_placeholder_16] => 18 [:db_condition_placeholder_17] => 19 [:db_condition_placeholder_18] => 20 [:db_condition_placeholder_19] => 21 [:db_condition_placeholder_20] => 22 [:db_condition_placeholder_21] => 23 [:db_condition_placeholder_22] => 24 [:db_condition_placeholder_23] => 25 [:db_condition_placeholder_24] => 26 [:db_condition_placeholder_25] => 27 [:db_condition_placeholder_26] => 28 [:db_condition_placeholder_27] => 29 [:db_condition_placeholder_28] => 30 [:db_condition_placeholder_29] => 31 [:db_condition_placeholder_30] => 33 [:db_condition_placeholder_31] => 34 [:db_condition_placeholder_32] => 35 [:db_condition_placeholder_33] => 36 [:db_condition_placeholder_34] => 37 [:db_condition_placeholder_35] => 38 [:db_condition_placeholder_36] => 39 [:db_condition_placeholder_37] => 40 [:db_condition_placeholder_38] => 41 [:db_condition_placeholder_39] => 42 [:db_condition_placeholder_40] => 43 [:db_condition_placeholder_41] => 44 [:db_condition_placeholder_42] => 45 [:db_condition_placeholder_43] => 46 [:db_condition_placeholder_44] => 47 [:db_condition_placeholder_45] => 48 [:db_condition_placeholder_46] => 49 [:db_condition_placeholder_47] => 50 [:db_condition_placeholder_48] => 51 [:db_condition_placeholder_49] => 52 [:db_condition_placeholder_50] => 53 [:db_condition_placeholder_51] => 54 [:db_condition_placeholder_52] => 55 [:db_condition_placeholder_53] => 56 [:db_condition_placeholder_54] => 57 [:db_condition_placeholder_55] => 58 ) in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 196 of C:\wamp\www\ukmarketplace\includes\entity.inc).

Please someone could help me, thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to run the update function. It looks like you have updated code but you haven't updated the database. http://www.yoursite.com/update.php

Comment: Trust me I know the reason I knew this was the same thing happened to me.

Comment: I trusted you and you came through for me.  Thanks @Pitchinnate!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I uninstalled the file_entity module. Downloading and enabling it (manually through the UI since Drush no longer worked), then `drush cc all` and disabling and uninstalling it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem and what I did was went to the file(in your case entity.inc line 196) where the problem was encountered then I comment the line itself then I tried to update the website it didn't work, then i comment other couples line above and below that line then my update.php works but with errors then I went back to that file again and uncomment the lines and my site was back and running. My error came when I did an update on my install(hook_schema) file without running the update.php.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem:
When I enabled some modules and restart my computer, I found my drupal test site couldn't start, of course I was not able to run update.php, nor clear cache as others suggested. 
I access mysql server, and alter the table FILE_MANAGED, adding a TYPE column. And then, I tried my drupal test site, it working. And I can now login as admin, to continue work - the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Probable root cause was write access rights on sites/all/modules directories during module installation.

I have successfully fixed a similar issue with webform module applying the following process with drush.

```
$ drush dis webform # disable target module
$ drush pmu webform # uninstall target module - probable warnings
```

Remove the complete webform (or modulename) directory in serveur

```
$ rm -rf <drupal path>/sites/all/modules/webform
$ drush cc all # flush all caches - probable warning
```

Remove webform (or modulename) related tables in SQL database with msyql cmd

```
mysql -u root -p;
MYSQL> use <drupaldatabase>;
MYSQL> DROP TABLE webform, webform_component, webform_conditional, webform_conditional_actions, webform_conditional_rules, webform_emails, webform_last_download, webform_roles, webform_submissions, webform_submitted_data;
```

Insure correct rights on /sites/all/modules eg

```
$ chown -R me:www-data <drupal path>/sites/all/modules
$ chmdo -R 775 <drupal path>/sites/all/modules
```

Ready to enable desired module with drush

```
$ drush en webform # or desired module
$ drush cc all # flush all caches
```

Your module is correctly installed and available